# How to access cookie in an MVC3 action method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, http, cookies, controller

How can I access a cookie in an MVC3 application?

It's for a shopping cart, where users can add an item to their cart, meaning to their cookie.

On checkout I would read this cookie for a key value pair of `ProductId` and `Quantity` for the appropriate price fetching from the database and calculation.

Very simply, how do I check for cookie and read/write data to them from a Controller action method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read Cookie:

```
var cookie = Request.Cookies["key"];
```

Add Cookie:

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new System.Web.HttpCookie() { /* ... fill it up ... */ });
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525394(v=vs.90).aspx